# How to get existing session attributes after using sendRedirect()?

Tags: javascript, servlets

How I can get existing `session` attributes after using `sendRedirect()` method? If I am trying to get the data `session`, attributes. But they are null since it creates a new session after invoking this method.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Java? It would help people if you add the tag for the language you are using, otherwise it's going to be very difficult to get any solution!

Answer (score 0):

`response.sendRedirect()` does not magically create a new session.

To get an existing object from the current session, simply `request.getSession.getAttribute("attrKey")`.
Before that, You should already saved it by saying something like `request.getSession().setAttribute("attrKey", object);`

If that does not work, please check if the object is already null before you saved it in session
OR
If your browser's cookie is disabled.